# How can I declare a destructor in SystemC?

Tags: c++, destructor, systemc

I'm writing a module in SystemC where within the constructor I have a variable initialized with `new`:

```
SC_CTOR(MY_MODULE)
{
    ...
    ...
    my_matrix = new unsigned char [a*b];
    ...
    ...
}
```

How can I declare the destructor to release the memory when the simulation ends?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the C++ semantic. There is no equivalent of `SC_CTOR` for the destructor.

```
SC_MODULE(MyModule)
{
    SC_CTOR(MyModule)
    {
        my_matrix = new unsigned char [10];
    }

    ~MyModule() {
        delete my_matrix;
    }

private:
    unsigned char * my_matrix;
};
```